# AngularJS number filter fractionSize limited to 20 decimal places

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Why is number filter fractionSize in AngularJS limited to 20 decimal places?

```
Distance1<span ng-model='distance'>{{distance| number:20}}</span> <br />
```

outputs

> 1.00000000000000000000

But

```
Distance2<span ng-model='distance'>{{distance| number:21}}</span> <br />
```

outputs

> NaN.000000000000000000000

```js
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.distance = 1;
}]);
```

```css
span {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 12px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myModule' ng-controller='myController'>
  Distance1<span ng-model='distance'>{{distance| number:20}}</span> <br />
  Distance2<span ng-model='distance'>{{distance| number:21}}</span> <br />
  </div>
```

Comment: Basically its 20 decimal places. You can check it by changing `$scope.distance` to `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## original guess

While I was unable to find a reference in the Number filter's [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L79), I'm guessing somewhere deeper it is utilizing `Number.toFixed` which is limited to 20 decimal spaces. Per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

> The number of digits to appear after the decimal point; this may be a value between 0 and 20, inclusive, and implementations may optionally support a larger range of values. If this argument is omitted, it is treated as 0

## a better guess

I did some testing and I think it's a combination of the limits of the `Number.prototype.toFixed` having a maximum length of 20 plus the fact that in the filter's [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L3) there is `var MAX_DIGITS = 22`.  I ran the following tests to check my theory:

```
var $number = angular.injector().get('numberFilter')
$number(1, 20) // 1.00000000000000000000, 22 total chars
$number(1, 21) // NaN.000000000000000000000, 23 total chars (assuming if NaN evaluated to a single char)
$number(10, 20) // NaN.00000000000000000000
$number(10, 19) // 10.0000000000000000000
```

So as you can see, 22 doesn't refer to the actual numerical value, it seems to refer to the string length.  Still unclear as to how it can deal with `$number(0, 21)` and not output the NaN string.